# Can't install twython on Python 3.2 (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python-3.x, module, twython

I'm trying to install [twython](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but keep getting errors.

First attempt:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/twython $ sudo pip-3.2 install twython
```

> ```
>  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
>       File "/home/pi/twython/build/requests/setup.py", line 52, in <module>
>         exec(f.read(), about)
>       File "<string>", line 14
>         __cake__ = u'\u2728 \U0001f370 \u2728'
>                                              ^
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
>
>   File "/home/pi/twython/build/requests/setup.py", line 52, in <module>
>
>     exec(f.read(), about)
>
>   File "<string>", line 14
>
>     __cake__ = u'\u2728 \U0001f370 \u2728'
>
>                                          ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ----------------------------------------
> Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/pi/twython/build/requests
> ```

Next I searched on the last line of the error and followed some suggestions that said to make sure `setuptools` and `ez_install` were installed and up to date, but that didn't help.

Then I followed the backup instructions on ReadtheDocs that said to try to install it this way:

```
git clone git://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython.git
cd twython
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

but it failed again:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 640, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 692, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 822, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 834, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 608, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 638, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 828, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1105, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1094, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 31, in run_setup
    lambda: exec(compile(open(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 73, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 34, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'})
  File "setup.py", line 52, in <module>

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: None of those documentation pages use sudo, by the way (not that it matters for this error)

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, but if you don't use sudo you just get a message that you don't have permission. Thanks for fixing the error code formatting.

Comment: Update: I'm also reaching out on GitHub and Twitter to try to get some support for this and will update this post accordingly if there's any help from those channels

Comment: are you installing inside a `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Twython cannot work with Python v3.2 because it depends on the `requests` module which apparently is not supported in Python 3.2.

One of the developers of Twython just explained this to me on Twitter.